# How to simplify the expression $\csc18°*\sec36°$?

Tags: trigonometry

Please help me, I tried several methods but I do not understand how I can solve this other than substituting the actual values in the expression.

Comment: Do you mean $\csc 18^\circ$?

Comment: yes, I edited it

Comment: I suggest trying to use the double-angle formula on the expression.

Comment: any other method to solve this? I wasn't aware of this fact

Comment: @JasonKim I tried that already, didn't work. I probably missed an onward path while solving. Could you help?

Comment: why are you guys downvoting? Nobody has even answered

Comment: there is a proof for trig function of angles 18,36,54,72...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $$\csc18 \sec36=\frac{1}{\sin 18\cos 36}=\frac{2\cos 18}{\sin 36\cos 36}=\frac{4\cos 18}{\sin 72}=\frac{4\sin 72}{\sin 72}=4,$$ where I have used the transformation $2\sin x\cos x=\sin (2x)$ repeatedly, and $\cos(90-x)=\sin x$ in the penultimate equality. Finally, all arguments are in degrees.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sin 18^o = \frac{\sqrt5 -1}{4} \text{ and } \cos 36^o = \frac{\sqrt5 +1}{4}$$
If you didn't know these you can search their proofs on the internet.
Thus, $$\csc 18^o = \frac{4}{\sqrt5 -1} \text{ and } \sec 36^o = \frac{4}{\sqrt5 +1}$$
$$\implies \csc 18^o \cdot \sec 36^o = \frac{4}{\sqrt5 -1}\cdot\frac{4}{\sqrt5 +1}= \frac{16}{4} = 4$$

Answer (score 0):

Using the same knowledge as in @rash's answer, an alternative is to let $\theta=\frac{\pi}{10}$ so you want $$\frac{1}{\sin\theta\cos 2\theta}=\frac{2}{\sin 3\theta-\sin\theta}=\frac{2}{\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{4}-\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{4}}=4.$$